# Django Choices Display Values

Tags: python, django, unicode

Model.py:

```
class RiskIssue(models.Model):
    RISK_ISSUE_SEVERITY = (
        ('L', 'Low'),
        ('M', 'Medium'),
        ('H', 'High'),
    )
    projectRiskIssueSeverity = models.CharField("Risk/Issue Severity",
                      max_length=1, choices=RISK_ISSUE_SEVERITY, default='L')
```

View.py code:

```
cell = table.rows[2].cells[0]
formatted_status = [astatus.get_projectRiskIssueSeverity_display() for
              astatus in activitylist.values_list('activityStatus', flat=True)]
cell.paragraphs[0].text = ', '.join(formatted_status)
```

I am getting the error code: `'unicode' object has no attribute 'get_projectRiskIssueSeverity_display'`

What am I doing wrong? I have tried everything except the correct answer. Very small TypeError problem here I assume `activitylist` is a unicode object and does not need activitylist.objects before it.

The issue here is: the `astatus.get_projectRiskIssueSeverity_display()`, This is not working as expected according to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display

Answer (score 2):

Note that `get_FOO_display()` is an instance method on the model. `.values_list()` doesn't return any model instances, so the value won't have any `get_FOO_display()` methods.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `get_FOO_display()` on model instances only. Use intermediate dictionary to get the display name from the pure status value:

```
severity_d = dict(RiskIssue.RISK_ISSUE_SEVERITY)
formatted_status = [severity_d[astatus] for astatus in
                    activitylist.values_list('activityStatus', flat=True)]
```